# Tomcat jdbc connection "nullpointerexception" for realm

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jdbc

I'm trying to use realm for security in servlet.

this is the realm part of WEB-IF/web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>X</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/karbar/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>karbar</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Y</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/modir/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>modir</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-role>
    <role-name>modir</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>karbar</role-name>
</security-role>
```

And this is realm tag in tomcat's server.xml:

```
<Realm
            className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
            driverName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            conncetionURL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"
                connectionName="kian"
                connectionPassword="myjava123"
                userTable="users"
                userNameCol="name"
                userCredCol="password"
                userRoleTable="roles"
                roleNameCol="user_role"
   />
```

I have also copied `classes12.jar` in `apache-tomcat-7.0.19\lib`

The problem is that now web-server gets disconnected with this error:

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.19
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:358)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.open(JDBCRealm.java:711)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.startInternal(JDBCRealm.java:782)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1026)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:621)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
Disconnected from server
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry folks. I think it was a bug in intelliJ 12.0 or tomcat or something!
Just to check the jdbc driver I ran another project I knew should run fine. It did, then I return to the project above and it worked  fine too!

I have no idea what happened. Why there was an issue and why all of sudden it went away.